# $("input:checked").length not working in opera after go back in browser history

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have JavaScript witch contain this code:

```
$("input:checked").length
```

After go back button clicked in browser this code $("input:checked").length; not working in opera. Is there anything i can do?

Basically I need to check if there was two radio-buttons checked or not

```
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#signup").button();

        $("#signup").click(function () {

            alert($("#bb input:checked").length);
            if ($("#bb input:checked").length == 2) {
                $("#signup").val("1");                
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="bb"> 
       <div id="rbl1" class="rbl1">
           <input type="radio" id="rb11" name="radio-b1" value="1"/><label for="rb11" class="radio">Everyday</label>
           <input type="radio" id="rb12" name="radio-b1" value="2"/><label for="rb12" class="radio">Saturday</label>
        </div>        

        <div id="rbl2" class="rbl2">
           <input type="radio" id="rb21" name="radio-b2" value="1"/><label for="rb21" class="radio">One</label>
           <input type="radio" id="rb22" name="radio-b2" value="2"/><label for="rb22" class="radio">Two</label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<button name="submit" id="signup">Sugn up</button>
}
```

First time it is working well in all browsers, after radio buttons checked i submitting my form in that time everything fine. But then i just checked whats happened if i go back in browser history and submit form again, so all browsers fine except opera, it is failing on this code line $("#bb input:checked").length == 2) and didn't give any details why.

Before i used jQuery 1.5.1 now i updated to 1.5.2 and still the same problem.
Detailed sample code updated, full html code posted here http://sourcepod.com/puvmmz30-4571

Probably something with Opera history going wrong.

Is there somehow else i may set value of $("#signup").val("1"); or check if radio list selected ("#bb input:checked") and Opera history didn't clear that.

Comment: What version of jquery do you have? Did you try with the latest?

Comment: what do you mean it fails? What happens? Have you tried alerting to see what the value actually is?

Comment: i put 'debugger' statement to see whats happened in opera dragonfly, the value of '("#bb input:checked").length == is 0, but it should be not 0

Comment: @Reg It could be that Opera is showing you page from the history and not actually reloading/refreshing the page. Do you have a test page we can look at?

Comment: Full html source code posted here http://www.sourcepod.com/puvmmz30-4571

Comment: @Reg could you add `$('.radio').removeAttr('checked')` before the click event just to reset anything opera might have set up in its history? Also, when adding a comment make sure to say @JohnP otherwise I won't get a notification :)

Comment: @JohnP If i put  $('input:radio').removeAttr('checked'); it would remove all selections from radio list. There is something with Opera history going wrong i guess.

Comment: @Reg, that's the thing. Opera might be keeping state somewhere. This doesn't seem to be matching up with the DOM. I don't know enough of how Opera handles it :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `size()` rather than `length`?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/ they doing the same ,var n = $("input:checked").length;,

Comment: Yes, but `length` is an inherent part of JavaScript. `size()` is browser-independent...

Comment: No, it is returns the same 0 instead correct value, because basically size() getting value of .length

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this problem using Opera 12.12 and jQuery 1.6.1.
I cannot reproduce this if I upgrade jQuery to 1.9.1.

If you can't upgrade your jQuery version, you can get the correct checked value using .each() and value.checked.

See:
$(".reasons input").each(function(index, value) {console.log(value.checked, value)})

It returns the correct values for checked.